# Dealing with Comments in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently, I'm making a simple blog-like app, where a user can make a post, and several other users can comment on it.

Is there a way to have a polymorphic attribute belong to more than one Model?

For example,

a Comment will always have an author (User model)
However, a Comment can belong to many other models (Posts, Journals, Articles, etc etc)

so, for (Posts, Journals, Articles) models, polymorphic association is best.
However, for the author (or User relationship), polymorphic would not work, since polymorphic can only belong to one at a time.

Is there a better way around this?

EDIT:
What are the pros/cons of doing this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

EDIT2:
with the solution above, is there a more elegant way of doing this

```
def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

    if @comment.save
        flash[:success] = 'Comment created'
        redirect_to @commentable
    else
        flash[:error] = 'Comment not created - is body empty?'
        redirect_to @commentable
    end
end
```

without having to save the user_id manually in the controller?

```
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have both a `User` relationship as well as a polymorphic relationship representing the model it is associated with. For example:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :document, polymorphic: true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :document
end

class Journal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :document
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :document
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

Now, you can call `comment.user` to get the `User` model for the person who created the comment and `comment.document` to get the `Post`, `Journal`, or `Article` that the comment is associated with.

Comment: Sorry, what's your take on my EDIT2?

Comment: Similar to how you can get the models with `comment.user` and `comment.document`, you can also assign them: `comment.user = current_user` and `comment.document = current_document`. When you `save` the comment, it'll correctly assign the `user_id`, `document_id`, and `document_type` columns in your database.

Comment: In terms of elegance though, what you're doing is fine.